# Python turtle color

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Hey I have to make a program in python that takes input from the user for number of rows, columns, square side length, and three colors. Then the program must make a grid according to the number of rows and columns, and fill in the squares in an alternating checker pattern. I have it coded up to the point where it fills in the colors, and i was wondering if anyone could help me. Here's what i have so far:

```
from turtle import *
t = Turtle()
screen = t.getscreen()

rows = screen.numinput('Number of rows',
                       'How many rows shall there be?', 5, 1, 10)
columns = screen.numinput('Number of columns',
                          'How many columns shall there be?', 5, 1, 10)
side_length = screen.numinput('Length of square side',
                              'How long shall the square sides be?', 30, 10, 50)
first_color = screen.textinput('First color',
                               'What shall the first color be?')
second_color = screen.textinput('Second color',
                                'What shall the second color be?')
third_color = screen.textinput('Third color',
                               'What shall the third color be?')

square_color = ''


def draw_square():
    t.begin_fill()
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(side_length)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(side_length)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(side_length)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(side_length)
    t.color(square_color)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
    t.color('black')
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(side_length)



def draw_board():
    n = 1
    for i in range(int(columns)):
        draw_square()
    for x in range(int(rows - 1)):
        t.goto(0,side_length * n)
            for i in range(int(columns)):
            draw_square()
        n += 1
for i in range(int(columns)):
    for x in range(int(rows)):
        if x + i % 3 == 0:
            square_color = first_color
        elif x + i % 3 == 1:
            square_color = second_color
        elif x + i % 3 == 2:
            square_color = third_color
draw_board()
done()
```

Comment: You were wondering if anyone could help you do what? What is your question?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The user is very clear with his asking, Which part of the question you need help in understanding ?

Comment: @itsneo - If it's very clear for you, please share it with me. What is the question? Keep in mind that "could someone please pick up where I left off and complete this program for me?" is not a question.

Comment: @itsneo I don't understand - is problem to fill one square or to create checker pattern ?

Comment: btw: use `def draw_square(side_length, square_color):` and run it with arguments.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mean for it to be a "please finish my code" kinda post, i just needed help fixing my program so it would color in the squares, and my double for loop wasn't working. I just needed someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Sorry about that; If my boss comes and tells me "The program must make a grid according to the number of rows and columns, and fill in the squares in an alternating checker pattern", I will right away start working on it. Because I feel its a verily clear requirement. Besides the user is new the to community and he/she has done the best.

Comment: @itsneo - "If my boss..." You seem to be under the impression that this site matches software development managers with unpaid volunteers, but in fact it is a repository of programming questions and answers that may be useful to other programmers. Please see the [help] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the code you need, in fact too much. You just don't have it assembled correctly.  You need to think of your program as a story and tell that story in the correct order of events such that the story makes sense.  Below is my rework of your code to put things in a better order along with some style tweaks and code cleanup:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def draw_square(turtle, length, color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(length)

def draw_board(turtle, length, colors):
    n = 0

    for row in range(int(rows)):
        turtle.goto(0, length * n)
        for column in range(int(columns)):
            square_color = colors[(column + row) % len(colors)]
            draw_square(turtle, length, square_color)
        n += 1

screen = Screen()

rows = screen.numinput('Number of rows', 'How many rows shall there be?', 5, 1, 10)
columns = screen.numinput('Number of columns', 'How many columns shall there be?', 5, 1, 10)
side_length = screen.numinput('Length of side', 'How long shall the square sides be?', 30, 10, 50)

first_color = screen.textinput('First color', 'What shall the first color be?')
second_color = screen.textinput('Second color', 'What shall the second color be?')
third_color = screen.textinput('Third color', 'What shall the third color be?')

colors = [first_color, second_color, third_color]

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()

draw_board(turtle, side_length, colors)

turtle.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

**PRODUCES:**

[image]